# Wrap div if MYSQL column same

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I've created a pretty standard output script that spits out a list from my database `WHERE bv_category="Smart"` and they are also ordered by subcategory+id.

All is well and good, but I'd like to further enhance this by splitting this up into separate divs so as to provide more grouping -- "visually". It's a pretty standard table at this point.

So for those with the same bv_subcategory would be placed into a separate div container. I'd style accordingly each one. Any tips on achieving this?

I tried an if within the for each, but that would insert a div for each one where as I'd want to wrap each one that has the same bv_subcategory value.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_products_table_ba_BV_unique";

    if (! empty ( $sql_filter )) {
        $query .= ' WHERE bv_category="Smart" AND ' . implode ( ' AND ', $sql_filter ) . ' ORDER BY bv_subcategory ASC, id ASC';
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_products_table_ba_BV_unique WHERE bv_category='Smart' ORDER BY bv_subcategory ASC, id ASC";
    }
     echo "SQL been Called : <br/>";
     echo "<b>" . $query . "</b>";

    $products = $wpdb->get_results ( $query );

    $prodTable_Build =  "<table id='myTable' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
$prodTable_Build .= "<thead class='productTableHead'> 
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Pack Size</th>
            <th>Exhibit A Grain<br />OZ. Equivalent</th>
            <th>Grain OZ.<br />Equivalent</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>";
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $bv_product_num = stripslashes ($product->bv_product_num);
    $bv_product_num_fix = str_pad($bv_product_num, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $bv_product_iw_bulk = stripslashes ($product->bv_product_iw_bulk);
    if($bv_product_iw_bulk == 1) {
        $bv_product_iw_bulk = "Bulk";
    }
    else 
        $bv_product_iw_bulk = "IW";
    $bv_id = stripslashes ($product->id);
    $bv_wg = stripslashes ($product->bv_wg);
    $bv_rf = stripslashes ($product->bv_rf);
    $bv_lf = stripslashes ($product->bv_lf);
    $bv_product_name = stripslashes ($product->bv_product_name);
    $bv_product_flavor = stripslashes ($product->bv_product_flavor);
    $bv_catering = stripslashes ($product->bv_catering);
    $bv_commodity_processed = stripslashes ($product->bv_commodity_processed);
    $bv_ex_a_equiv = stripslashes ($product->bv_ex_a_equiv);
    $bv_ex_a_equiv = number_format((float)$bv_ex_a_equiv, 2, '.', ''); 
    $bv_grain_equiv = stripslashes ($product->bv_grain_equiv);
    $bv_grain_equiv = number_format((float)$bv_grain_equiv, 2, '.', ''); 
    $bv_category = stripslashes ($product->bv_category);
    $bv_subcategory = stripslashes ($product->bv_subcategory);

    $bv_alliance = stripslashes ($product->bv_alliance);
    $upload_image1 = stripslashes ($product->upload_image1);
    $bv_pack_oz = (float)stripslashes ($product->bv_pack_oz);
    $bv_pack_quant = stripslashes ($product->bv_pack_quant);
    $bv_attached_pdf = stripslashes ($product->bv_attached_pdf);
    $bv_image_main = stripslashes ($product->bv_image_main);
    $bv_image_extra = stripslashes ($product->bv_image_extra);
    $prod_desc = stripslashes ($product->prod_desc);
    if($bv_alliance == 1) {
        $alianFix = "<img src='".WP_PLUGIN_URL."/bv-product-crud/icons/alliance-icon.png' />";
    }
    else{
        $alianFix = "";
    }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $uploadimageFix = "<a href='$bv_attached_pdf' target='_blank'>PDF</a>";
    } else {
        $uploadimageFix = "<a href='wp-login.php'>Log In</a>";
    }
        $prodTable_Build .= "<tr>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td>$bv_product_num_fix $bv_product_iw_bulk</td>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td><b>$alianFix $bv_wg $bv_rf $bv_lf $bv_product_name</b> <!--- $bv_subcategory--></td>"; 
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td>$bv_pack_oz oz./$bv_pack_quant</td>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td>$bv_ex_a_equiv</td>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td>$bv_grain_equiv</td>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "<td>$uploadimageFix</td>";
        $prodTable_Build .= "</tr>";
    }
    $prodTable_Build .= "</tbody></table>";
    $prodTable_Build .= "</div>";
    echo $prodTable_Build;
```

Comment: You could concatenate the data in to separate strings based on what your trying to collect, and then display each one later after the loop had finished!

Comment: Hi @user3633383 I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Do you mean card code the html and echo into separate areas of the site? Is there nota  way to dynamically create the blocks?

Comment: First I've been rewriting your code a bit. There were 2 syntax errors in it btw. After that I kinda hit your dilemma. It's pretty easy to do since you're already ordering it. All you have to do is save `$bv_category` in a different var and compare that with `$bv_category` on each loop to see if it's changed. Next you just build a new DIV everytime. The issue is the table itself. It starts outside of the loop, as it should, but therefor you can't end the table and create a new one on each new DIV. So ye, kinda stuck at that right now.

Comment: Hi @icecub can I take a look. Maybe I can resolve it?

Comment: Ye here it is: http://pastebin.com/gymuXtC0 The idea is in the comments. It was a work in progress though and definitely not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You get the idea

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ORDER BY `bv_subcategory`";

$temp = row['bv_subCategory'];
<div>
//in loop

if($temp != row['bv_subcategory'])
{
echo "</div><div>"
$temp = $row['bv_subcategory'];
}

//after loop
</div>
```